# Complexity of Least Common Multiple

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I would like to know the complexity of computing the least common multiple of $n$ natural numbers. Does it depend on Euler's totient function?

Comment: No totient, the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is $ab/gcd(a,b)$ and gcd is cheap, say via the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I am asking it for $n$ numbers not just $2$. But I think you may be right that the totient function is not related.

Comment: Can do one after the other, $\text{lcm}(\text{lcm}(a,b),c)$ and so on.  Good thing totient is not involved, since it is (currently) not cheap to compute.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Is it linear to $n$?

Comment: The real issue comes with the (in general) very rapidly growing size of the numbers. To keep that under control, it might be wiser to find the lcm in groups of $2$, then find the lcm again in groups of $2$ and so on.  I am hoping an expert in number-theoretic algorithms will answer, since I know there are implementations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: That is exactly why I asked this question. I do not think grouping in 2's and do 2 at a time is optimal. There are better algorithms for arbitrary number of natural numbers. However, I do not know the complexity of these algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that our numbers $(a_i)_i$ have at most $\alpha$ bits ($l(a_i)\leq \alpha$). We calculate the following values: $\gcd(a_1,a_2),{\rm lcm}(a_1,a_2),\gcd(\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2),a_3),{\rm lcm}(a_1,a_2,a_3),\cdots $. When $a>b$, the complexity (number of elementary operations with respect to bits) $C_G(a,b)$ of the calculation of $\gcd(a,b)$ satisfies $C_G(a,b)\leq l(a)l(b)+\lambda.l(b)^2$; then $C_L(a,b)$, the complexity of $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$, satisfies  $C_L(a,b)\leq 2.l(a)l(b)+\lambda.l(b)^2$. Note that $l({\rm lcm}(a_1,\cdots,a_k))\leq k\alpha$. Finally , the total complexity $C$ satisfies $C\leq (2\alpha ^2+\lambda\alpha ^2)+(4\alpha ^2+\lambda\alpha ^2)+(6\alpha ^2+\lambda\alpha ^2)+\cdots\leq (n²+n\lambda)\alpha ^2$.

Answer to Hans. Finally I don't think that U: "a simple algorithm" (your reference in wiki) is  powerful. For instance, consider $lcm(99,100,101,103)=99.100.101.103$. U uses $\approx 10^6$ additions of the form $p+a$ where $a\in\{99,100,101,103\}$, that is an exponential complexity.

Comment: Is the algorithm $\gcd(a_1,a_2),{\rm lcm}(a_1,a_2),\gcd(\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,a_2),a_3),{\rm lcm}(a_1,a_2,a_3),\cdots$ the most efficient? Are these  computations truly necessary? Are other algorithms, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#A_simple_algorithm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#A_method_using_a_table better? What is the complexity for these algorithms?

Comment: The first algorithm in wikipedia "A simple algorithm"  seems to me interesting. I don't know its complexity. The second one is useless because it uses the list of prime numbers, which is inefficient for large numbers.

Comment: Just want to ascertain, "we must calculate the following values", particularly the word "must" does not actually mean these calculations are necessary for any general lcm computation but only for the particular algorithm you have in mind, right? Otherwise, could you please prove the claim?